# empty disk0 and formatting fails

Tags: disk-format

I have experienced a problem (a forbidden sign) so I booted with the install CD (on a iMac7.1). The disk utility didn't do, so I tried formatting the disk to start again, and it hasn't worked either.

Now from the terminal if I type
`diskutil list`

I obtain

```
#:           type name          size       identifier
0:                            *298.1 GB    disk0
```

and the DVD

```
/dev/disk1
#:           type name          size       identifier
0: Apple_partition_scheme       *5.1 GB    disk1
1:    Apple_partition_map       31.5 KB    disk1s1
```

etc.

I tried to format disk0 but it returns errors...
what should I do? My goal is to put it in state where I can run the disk installer and reinstall the system..

To format I first used the diskutility, but it returned an input/output error. Then I tried from the terminal

```
 diskutil eraseVolume  "Journaled HFS+" ABC disk0 

Started erase on disk disk0

Erasing

MountingDisk

Finished erase on disk disk0
error with erase The underlying task reported failure on exit (-9972) 

Finished erase on disk disk0
```

Comment: How did you try to format it, what kind of errors did you get (screenshot preferred)? Which version of macOS are you trying to install?

Comment: Is the Mac model something like this here? https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.4-20-inch-aluminum-specs.html

Comment: @nohillside : yes that model. I have added the diskutility result. Can't do screen image since the machine isn't the one I am writing from.

Comment: The HDD might be broken, especially if you got the forbidden sign earlier.